# Advanced file handling with workflow

Tags: files, workflows

I have a field with type file. The whole content type follows the workflow process. As of now, when a new file is added to the new revision, it automatically gets renamed and the recent file will be dispalyed.
My requirement is, while the node is still is in draft state, i need to display the recent file with the new name file_name_0.pdf. Once the node is published, i still the need the file name to be origin i.e file_name.pdf.
Thanks in advance.